# how to change the site to particular location in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, search, filter, hook

For example,

I have a domain.com. If the user searches domain.com/toronto. I need the complete site should show the posts and article related to that city.

so I planned to do

take city(toronto) from search query

1.search with the geolocation api if it is valid place, 
2.get the lat long, 
3.fix it in cookie, until another search is done to update.

I used `pre_get_posts` and `parse_query` to get the city. but I did not get nothing, please someone suggest which hooks to use and need to understand the wordpress hooks and filters quickly.

Comment: so i m assuming your city is your category.

So if your category link will be 'site.com/cat1' and posts under it will be like  'site.com/cat1/post1'

But what about other pages like contact us ?

i m asking bcoz its possible to make your site read site.com/cat1 but the moment you put 'site.com/contactus', it will think this contact us as separate category too.

Just a thaught.

Comment: @Alice thanks, my site is directory listing. So if the user types domain.com/london. I need the site shall show everything related to london. Any plugin us also helpful. Or else any hook available to get the search string in url before performing search. I tried `pre_get_posts` and `parse_query` but cant able to get the london

Comment: not a hook, your first concern should be .htaccess to read it (london) from url and permalink. go through those a bit u will discover.

Comment: I am using listingo wordpress theme, in that the geolocation is auto-detect, likewise I need to check that string domain.com/london, if it is a place I need to change the query, if it is page domain.com/contact then the normal search needs to be performed.

Comment: so now if you type site.com/london what is showing ? page can't find ?

If so .... can you please check query_vars ?

if yes (london exists in query_args) then pre_get_posts may help

Comment: can you please print prese query array too , to see whether 'london' is there in variable name - 'page' ?

Comment: Alice I cant able to get the string "london" in query vars filter. any other suggestions pls.

Comment: can you print your query vars array here ?

Comment: @Alice comment does not allow large characters. pls see in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found, a hook is there before showing the 404 page,

So in that, used `$wp_query->query['name']` to get the search query text i.e. london or toronto.

Then using that I checked with the google maps API for valid place. once its valid then I redirected to the search url with that location. which I found in themes normal search with geolocation. Please use the below code in your themes functions.php.

In some of the places I used my themes functions

1. fw_get_db_settings_option
2. And in myredirect_url use your themes normal search url with geolocation

```
add_filter('template_redirect', 'my_404_override' );
function my_404_override() {
    global $wp_query;
    $mysearch_location = $wp_query->query['name'];

    $google_key = '';

    if (function_exists('fw_get_db_settings_option')) {
        $google_key = trim(fw_get_db_settings_option('google_key'));
    }

    $protocol = is_ssl() ? 'https' : 'http';

    $place_detail = file_get_contents($protocol .'://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query='.$mysearch_location.'&key='.$google_key);

    $place_detail = json_decode($place_detail);

    $formatted_address = $place_detail->results[0]->formatted_address;
    $latitude = $place_detail->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
    $longitude = $place_detail->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

    if($place_detail->status=='OK'){
        status_header( 200 );
        $wp_query->is_404=false;
        $myredirect_url = get_site_url() .'/find/?keyword=&geo='.$formatted_address.'&geo_distance=11&lat='.$latitude.'&long='.$longitude.'&location='.$formatted_address.'&category=';
        wp_redirect( $myredirect_url );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Manual way just  move all file to server and database to phpmyadmin newly created database .

After that add credentials in root wp-config file for your database host and also add

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
```

Updated  example.com with you domain name which is connected to your hosting .

To your wp-config file .

Other  way Use Duplicator plugin for same to easily migrate site

> If you want to create many sub sites you need to use multi-site
>   network in word-press in that way you can create separate sites for
>   different locations .

Comment: if the user search domain.com/london means need to create another site as suggested by you?. This is not the correct answer and not related to my question.

Comment: Yes if  you want to  run site in /london not on root domain.com   you can pass domain.com/london in config url for same and also files with the mentioned folder name

Comment: my question is fully related to search in particular domain. not configuring/mapping to sub folder

Comment: Yes  if you want different site for /london  then you need to  create a one for london  Other way is to enable multisite network in which from same admin you can create as many sites

Comment: do you know justdial, whether they are running each site for each location?

Comment: thats in different platform i think i am  only mentioning you as per  wordpress and  multisite network is best for that

Comment: @DroidDev  I think it would be better if you use your location as category in WordPress so if user visits domain.com/toronto, it will show posts otherwise redirect all 404 pages to homepage.(Using any plugin or function)

Comment: @HritikPandey I used service providers type as category, because listingo theme is framed like that.